# Simplest way to append Bloomberg API data to a MySQL table using Java

Tags: java, mysql, bloomberg

I would like to append a Bloomberg API response to a MySQL database using Java.

At the moment I query the API and display the response using the below code:

```
    session.sendRequest(request, null);

    while (true) {
        Event event = session.nextEvent();
        MessageIterator msgIter = event.messageIterator();
        while (msgIter.hasNext()) {
              Message msg = msgIter.next();
              new JSONObject(msg);
              System.out.println(msg);
        }
        if (event.eventType() == Event.EventType.RESPONSE) {
            break;
        }
    }
```

I would like to be able to append the `msg` object to a table in a MySQL database. The `msg` object looks like it is a JSON format (although I am unsure how to confirm this).

I also have no problems connecting to the MySQL table using JDBC.

Comment: And what is the question? How confirm format or how to save this to MySQL? About Java + MySQL just google little bit: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm, change select sql to update in your case.

Comment: How do I update MySQL using a JSON object? (Step 5 of the link you sent me)

Comment: Too long answer to comment... Read below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 5 connected with select query, in you case at step 4 you need use update query and no step 5 will be required. You need to get fields values from json and put them in update statement. To get values from json:

```
//example json string
String json = "{paramsArray: [\"first\", 100],"
        + "paramsObj: {one: \"two\", three: \"four\"},"
        + "paramsStr: \"some string\"}";

JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

Object obj = parser.parse(json);
JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) obj;
System.out.println(jsonObj.get("paramsStr"));

JsonObject jo = jsonObj.get("paramsObj");
System.out.println(jo.get("three"));
// output will be 'four'
```

Here reference to update query in mysql: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html